# SKSpriteKit. Can the SKScene be used as a physical body to pin an SKNode?

Tags: ios8, sprite-kit, skscene, sknode

I want to fix an SKNode (the node has a physics body) in space by pinning it to the SKScene. So it can participate in the physics simulation - collide, spin, etc. But **not** move. Is this allowable? Is there a better way to fix an physical node in space yet have it participate in the physics simulation?

Comment: make it an edge-based body

Comment: Ah hah! lightbulb has gone off in my head. Pose this as an answer and I will give it to you. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, by setting `dynamic` property to `NO`:

```
node.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
```

Comment: Nicael, but SKScene is inherently edge-based (ie, dynamic = no) so there should be no need to set it explicitly. No?

Comment: @dugla I mean that you should set this for SKNode... or am I misunderstanding the question?

Comment: I want an SKNode - SKSpriteNode typically - to be pinned in space using the SKScene as the pin board. So the SKScene is a pin board, each sprite has a pin, I pin the sprite to the pinboard.

Comment: @dulga So whats wrong with my answer?? Set the `physicsBody.dynamic` of this SKNode to `NO`.